# Manage the memory of objects calling a delegate callback block

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

Say I have a class ObjectA (a view controller for example), that does this :

```
ObjectB *objectB = [[ObjectB alloc] init];

[objectB executeLongRequestThenDo:^ (NSDictionary *results)
 {
     self.datasource = results;
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }];
```

ObjectA can be deallocated at any moment, so I should be able to cancel the request of objectB, and tell it not to execute the block when its done, right ? Simply releasing it is not enough ? Also, should I call `release` just after `executeLongRequestThenDo:` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `ObjectA` will not be deallocated at any moment -- it will be retained until `ObjectB` is done with the operation.

Probably `-[ObjectB executeLongRequestThenDo:]` will call `Block_copy` on the block. This will cause the block to be moved from the stack to the heap, and will retain all the `NSObject`s that the block directly references, namely `self`.

When `ObjectB` is done, it should run the block, then call `Block_release`, which will release `self`.  Or, if you have some way of canceling the operation, `ObjectB` should similarly release the block.

(It's possible that ObjectB will do this all indirectly, by calling something that does the work, like `dispatch_async`.)

Reference: [Blocks Programming Topics.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1)

As for when you should release `objectB`: it depends on whether it retains itself during the long-running operation, or not. To be safe, I would not release it until you know it's fully complete, which would be at the end of your block, or after you've called its cancellation method.